# Branching elimination using bitwise operators

Tags: c++, optimization, bit-manipulation

I have some critical branching code inside a loop that's run about 2^26 times. Branch prediction is not optimal because `m` is random. How would I remove the branching, possibly using bitwise operators?

```
bool m;
unsigned int a;
const unsigned int k = ...; // k >= 7
if(a == 0)
    a = (m ? (a+1) : (k));
else if(a == k)
    a = (m ?     0 : (a-1));
else
    a = (m ? (a+1) : (a-1));
```

And here is the relevant assembly generated by `gcc -O3`:

```
.cfi_startproc
movl    4(%esp), %edx
movb    8(%esp), %cl
movl    (%edx), %eax
testl   %eax, %eax
jne L15
cmpb    $1, %cl
sbbl    %eax, %eax
andl    $638, %eax
incl    %eax
movl    %eax, (%edx)
ret
L15:
cmpl    $639, %eax
je  L23
testb   %cl, %cl
jne L24
decl    %eax
movl    %eax, (%edx)
ret
L23:
cmpb    $1, %cl
sbbl    %eax, %eax
andl    $638, %eax
movl    %eax, (%edx)
ret
L24:
incl    %eax
movl    %eax, (%edx)
ret
.cfi_endproc
```

Comment: Before you jump into this, you might want to make sure the compilers you care about aren't actually able to optimize these into conditional moves.

Comment: Is 0<=a<=k a valid assumption?

Comment: @Eric Yes, 0<=a<=k is always true.

Comment: I'm quite surprised that GCC isn't able to turn the inner branches into conditional moves. The ones you have here are a lot simpler than the one in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array) where `-O3` does the job.

Comment: Looks like it's basically `a = a + (m?1:-1) % k`; One branch which a two-element LUT could fix. Or have I got negative modulo wrong...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The branch-free division-free modulo *could* have been useful, but testing shows that in practice, it isn't.

```
const unsigned int k = 639;
void f(bool m, unsigned int &a)
{
    a += m * 2 - 1;
    if (a == -1u)
        a = k;
    else if (a == k + 1)
        a = 0;
}
```

Testcase:

```
unsigned a = 0;
f(false, a);
assert(a == 639);
f(false, a);
assert(a == 638);
f(true, a);
assert(a == 639);
f(true, a);
assert(a == 0);
f(true, a);
assert(a == 1);
f(false, a);
assert(a == 0);
```

Actually timing this, using a test program:

```
int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i != 10000; i++)
    {
        unsigned int a = k / 2;
        while (a != 0) f(rand() & 1, a);
    }
}
```

(Note: there's no `srand`, so results are deterministic.)

My original answer: 5.3s

The code in the question: 4.8s

Lookup table: 4.5s (`static unsigned lookup[2][k+1];`)

Lookup table: 4.3s (`static unsigned lookup[k+1][2];`)

Eric's answer: 4.2s

This version: 4.0s

Comment: Wow! Your version is indeed faster than mine and others, it shaved about 7 nanosecs off of 30 nanosecs / loop. Great improvement! Thanks for all your effort!

Answer (score 4):

The fastest I've found is now the table implementation

Timings I got  (UPDATED for new measurement code)

HVD's most recent: 9.2s

Table version: 7.4s (with k=693)

Table creation code:

```
    unsigned int table[2*k];
    table_ptr = table;
    for(int i = 0; i < k; i++){
      unsigned int a = i;
      f(0, a);
      table[i<<1] = a;

      a = i;
      f(1, a);
      table[i<<1 + 1] = a;
    }
```

Table runtime loop:

```
void f(bool m, unsigned int &a){
  a = table_ptr[a<<1 | m];
}
```

With HVD's measurement code, I saw the cost of the rand() dominating the runtime, so that the runtime for a branchless version was about the same range as these solutions.  I changed the measurement code to this (UPDATED to keep random branch order, and pre-computing random values to prevent rand(), etc. from trashing the cache)

```
int main(){
  unsigned int a = k / 2;
  int m[100000];
  for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++){
    m[i] = rand() & 1;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i != 10000; i++
  {
    for(int j = 0; j != 100000; j++){
      f(m[j], a);  
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice! I created a test program and measured, the original version takes ~4.8s, my branch-free version takes ~5.3s so doesn't buy anything (which I had noted in my now deleted answer), yours takes ~4.2s.

Comment: Wow. The branch-free division-free modulo is *still* worse than branching. See my new answer.

Comment: I'm not seeing the benefits you get in your latest version. Yes, `rand()` will take up most of the time, but the time it's taking should be constant, so that doesn't matter, the absolute difference between the different versions is still a useful measurement. I get ~4.3s with that version.

Comment: Either way, I just checked and think a table-lookup significantly beats both of our solutions.

Comment: I already included that in my tests, and it doesn't (probably because it accesses memory in an unpredictable order).

Comment: Try without the call the rand() possibly knocking parts of the table out of cache each time.

Comment: Will do so later, but I would like to leave the unpredictable switches between `f(false, ...)` and `f(true, ...)`. In your version, you call one or the other 100000 times in a row, which could make a huge difference, especially if `f` gets inlined.

Comment: Updated to maintain random branching order.

Comment: More bad news for testing: in your test code, I get nothing at all: gcc has inlined `f`, determined that the entire loop does nothing, and removed it.

Comment: But if I change my test program to `while (a != 0) f(m[++j] & 1, a);`, where `j` is `unsigned short` and `m` is `int[65536]` filled with `rand()` results, table lookup is still slower in my testing.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can remove the branches entirely, but you can reduce the number by branching on m first.

```
if (m){
    if (a==k) {a = 0;} else {++a;}
}
else {
    if (a==0) {a = k;} else {--a;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Antimony's rewrite:

```
if (a==k) {a = 0;} else {++a;}
```

looks like an increase with wraparound. You can write this as

```
a=(a+1)%k;
```

which, of course, only makes sense if divisions are actually faster than branches.

Not sure about the other one; too lazy to think about what the (~0)%k will be.

Comment: +1, gcc optimises divisions by constants very well (replacing it by multiplications that rely on integer overflow), but it should be `% (k + 1)`. For the subtraction, just add another `k + 1` before subtracting 1 and getting the remainder: `a = (a + k) % (k + 1);`

Comment: I've expanded on your answer in my own.

Answer (score 1):

This has no branches. Because K is constant, compiler might be able to optimize the modulo depending on it's value. And if K is 'small' then a full lookup table solution would probably be even faster.

```
bool m;
unsigned int a;
const unsigned int k = ...; // k >= 7
const int inc[2] = {1, k};

a = a + inc[m] % (k+1);
```

Answer (score 1):

If k isn't large enough to cause overflow, you could do something like this:

```
int a; // Note: not unsigned int
int plusMinus = 2 * m - 1;
a += plusMinus;
if(a == -1) 
    a = k; 
else if (a == k+1) 
    a = 0;
```

Still branches, but the branch prediction should be better, since the edge conditions are rarer than m-related conditions.